# pthreads signal a specific thread

Tags: c, pthreads

In pthreads, is it possible for a thread to wake up another thread *given only the other thread's id*?

(Kind of like, calling pthread_cond_signal() but with also a specific, known, thread id in mind)

Answer (score 4):

You may try using `sigaction()` and `pthread_kill()`.

Comment: Beat me by 33 seconds though ;) once I get some more votes, I'll visit again. :) (It's a good thing there is a daily vote limit though, otherwise I might never go to bed. :)

Answer (score 3):

See the discussion between @Sam Hocevar and myself in response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282099/signal-handling-in-pthreads); the documentation says `pthread_kill(3)` delivers a signal to a specific thread, and I'm less sure about the Linux implementation sticking true to this requirement.

Comment: Correct, sane Linux implementations follow this requirement. Only the legacy LinuxThreads junk (and dietlibc's lite LinuxThreads workalike) have the bogus behavior where threads act like processes.