# How can I tell a thread that is currently or will soon be blocking in poll() to do something?

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, pipe

I have a thread A that calls `poll()` in a loop. This thread is responsible for IO on incoming and outgoing connections. However, when thread B has opened an outgoing connection, it has to give it to A somehow. Do you think it'd be a good idea to have a pipe between threads A (reading side) and B (writing side) that B writes to after opening the socket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds reasonable. `poll` should be happy watching a pipe alongside your socket(s).

Comment: Ok, thanks - if there's no better way, I guess I'll have to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than an actual pipe, you could look at using a [socket pair](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/socketpair.2.html). You could create a [unix-domain](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/unix.7.html) socket pair and send messages to the blocked thread using `send()` or `sendmsg()`. This approach might be more convenient for you. Unix-domain sockets also support passing file descriptors between processes, although that's overkill for your application.

The other approach is to interrupt the call to `poll()` with a signal. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282265/pthreads-signal-a-specific-thread).