# Thread and system signals

Tags: c++, c, signals, posix

I'm programing a multithreaded program that needs to intercept system signals (such as SIGINT). I would like to know if there is a normalized way to "catch" these signals like:

- A Signal is sent, may any thread receive it or only the main() one ?
- Is there a Posix rule or a programming idiom that specifies how to handle this ?

Comment: If no thread ever blocked any signal, any thread might receive any signal. A signal is received once or never per process. Referring '*never*': For successively sent signals of the same type all but the first might be swallowed away by the OS. Further reading: `man sigaction`

Comment: Here is an article with examples describing Linux signals.  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/

Comment: Reading up on the actual system call `signal(2)` would also be productive.

Comment: Here is a stack overflow question on multi-threading and signals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282099/signal-handling-in-pthreads and here is the signal man page with links to other associated man pages http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is guaranteed that precisely one thread receives the signal, but it is also unspecified *which* thread that is.

The proper thing to do is to block signals on all threads but one, so that that thread alone deals with signal handling; or on Linux specifically block threads everywhere and set up a signalfd to catch signals — that way, you don't introduce any asynchronousity and signals become just one more file descriptor to read from.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked about POSIX, from man [signal(7)](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?signal%207)

> POSIX.1  distinguishes the notions of signals that are directed to the
>   process as a whole and signals that are directed to individual
>   threads.  **According to POSIX.1, a process-directed signal (sent using
>   kill(2), for example) should be handled by a single, arbitrarily
>   selected thread  within  the  process**.

So in short, it means a random thread will be chosen to handle the signal.