# sending signal between thread of differences process

Tags: c++, linux, unix, pthreads, signals

Is that possible to send signal between

- Process P1  having thread as T1 T2 T3
- Process P2  having thread as T4 T5 T6

My question is , is that possible that T4 will send signal to T3

Thank you very much for your kindly help
Den

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

Signals are sent to processes, not threads. It is the responsibility of each process to determine which thread(s) with handle incoming signals (see [POSIX threads and signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575106/posix-threads-and-signals)).

Thus sending a signal to a specific thread would require cooperation from the target process.