# Extensions to POSIX permitting select() or equivalent for process termination

Tags: multithreading, unix, events, posix, child-process

In POSIX there is no way to be notified via `select`/`poll` when a *specific* child process terminates.  The closest you can get is a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`, which interacts poorly with threads, might not be available at all in an interpreted language, and wakes you up when *any* child process terminates.  Entering the land of system-specific extensions, [`signalfd`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/signalfd) makes it easier to field `SIGCHLD` from your main event loop but doesn't completely solve either the threads problem or the interpreted-language problem, and again it wakes you up when *any* child process terminates; I don't know of any others that address this problem.

Does any modern incarnation of Unix provide a mechanism whereby, in an 100% race-free and thread-safe manner, you can be awakened from a call to `select`, `poll`, or similar (epoll, kqueue, ...) when a *specific* child process terminates?

Comment: Not an answer for the question, but if you can choose application design, you can use libevent or libev to unify processing of I/O and signal events and hide low-level details. Both of them are quite portable.

Answer (score 1):

Do you control or otherwise trust the children's process images, such that they can be assumed *not* to fiddle with an inherited resource?

Let each child inherit the write end of a `pipe` pair specific to that child.  The parent holds the read end of every pair and knows *a priori* which fd is associated with each child.  When a child terminates, the read end indicates a pending EOF, becoming "readable" for select/poll/etc.  That should work even on ancient Unix, and also in interpreted languages where you might not be able to co-opt their native SIGCHLD handling.

Separately, you could implement what you want on a modern system with a single thread in the parent nominated to handle (or accept) all SIGCHLDs.  That thread would then have to transform the reaped PIDs [into some other interthread communication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2700597/132382) like I/O or a condition variable.  It's not trivial, but it can be done race-free and thread-safe.  (And if you are already mixing threads and fork, I infer you're taking some precautions anyway.)

Answer (score 1):

**How can I wait for termination of specific children in a race-free manner?**

Here is a list of possible options for a case when:

- You don't control child.
- You don't control the whole parent code (e.g. you're writing a library) and:

  - can't set global `SIGCHLD` handler;
  - can't fetch any signal that should be handled by other code in parent.

---

**Preferred  solution**

If you are already using `select()` or `poll()`, you can just replace it with `pselect()` or `ppoll()` to wait for I/O *or* `SIGCHLD` at the same time.

If the call is interrupted with `SIGCHLD`, you can subsequently call *non-blocking* `waitpid()` for every monitored child.

This will work even if `SA_RESTART` is enabled for `SIGCHLD`, since `(p)select()` and `(p)poll()` are [never restarted](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

---

**Other options**

1. You can do a blocking call to `waitpid()` or `waitid()` in separate thread, which would wait for *specific* child and then, say, write message to pipe.
2. You can put your child process into different process groups and wait for multiple children in one call.
3. If creating a thread for every child is not an option, you can create single thread that loops calling `sigsuspend()` to wait `SIGCHLD` (without *fetching* it) and then subsequently calls non-blocking `waitpid()` for every monitored child.

---

**Notes**

Note that using `signalfd`, just like setting global `SIGCHLD` handler, can affect other code in parent, because you can fetch signal that someone else expects to handle.