multi-threading and catching signals
I've read through other answers that signals are delivered to any arbitrary thread; however, with my own testing:
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#include <thread>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
#include <vector>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
#include <chrono>                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
void foo(int i) {                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  while (true) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    std::cout << i << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));                                                                                                                                                                       
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
int main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  std::vector<std::thread> t;                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  for (int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) {                                                                                                                                                                                               
    t.emplace_back([=] {                                                                                                                                                                                                        
      foo(i);                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    });                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  }                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  for (auto& v : t)                                                                                                                                                                                                             
    v.join();                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

I determined three things:

if I do not detach or join, I get an abort from libc++abi
if I detach each thread as it's spawned, I immediately exit and see no output
if I join, there is the expected behavior, but a signal kills all threads

Could someone please explain these behaviors? I'm concerned primarily with getting all threads to exit on receiving a signal (with as little code as possible) but the behaviors are curious to me.
My thoughts on each of these are:

potentially undefined behavior
main exiting kills all threads (this strikes me as strange)
this last one is very unexpected, since I thought a signal is delivered to random thread and only kills that one


What signal did you test with and what was it sent to?

SIGINT to the running process @DavidSchwartz with C-c

Delivered to random thread? That would be an absolute mind to debug.

Documentation explaining point 1 (if I do not detach or join, I get an abort from libc++abi)

POSIX signals is where portability of C++ ends, because they are unique to POSIX platform. You have to have handlers to correctly process SIGINT and similar to not cause catastrophes or a zombie. Very similar anaolg would be message pump of WinAPI  required to process certain system messages.

Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575106/posix-threads-and-signals

@user4581301 isn't it that it is delivered to some arbitrary thread that doesn't block the signal?

You have no signal handler for SIGINT.  You'll get the default behavior for it on your platform, which is what you are seeing.

@user129393192 that is my understanding too. Since I'm using boost::asio::signal_set to catch signals, I also have this comment: "Threads inherit signal masks from their parent, so by blocking them on the main thread, we should be able to just unblock them on the asio thread and everything will arrive there.". And, so far, that seems to catch SIGINT on the thread where I expect it.

@Eljay does this mean if one thread calls 'exit' for the process, they all terminate? i believe this may also explain the behavior with 'detach', since my understanding is that main returning calls the same 'exit' that is called with SIGINT by default.

@user129393192 • Yes, std::exit will exit the process.  If there was a signal handler, they are very constrained as to what they can do.  Because they can be invoked at any arbitrary time, even in the middle of some critical section — and I vaguely recall that a signal handler may be invoked by any available thread, not restricted to just the main thread (but I may be mistaken on that point).

Bullet 1:


if I do not detach or join, I get an abort from libc++abi


I presume you mean:
libc++abi: terminating

That's what I get too.
As main returns, ~vector<thread>() runs for t, which destructs each thread.  The spec for ~thread() is:

Effects: If joinable(), invokes terminate ([except.terminate]). Otherwise, has no effects.

A thread is joinable() is its get_id() member function does not return a default constructed thread​::​id.  This happens if a thread has been constructed to run a function and not been joined or detached.
Therefore the first thread that gets destructed in the destructor of t calls terminate and ends the process.  As the process ends, still running threads that touch destructed objects will invoke undefined behavior.  If they manage to avoid that, they simply disappear when control is handed back to the OS.
Bullet 2:


if I detach each thread as it's spawned, I immediately exit and see no output


As execution flows off of the end of main, exit(0) is implicitly called.  The spec:

If control flows off the end of the compound-statement of main, the effect is equivalent to a return with operand 0 (see also [except.handle]).

If a detached thread touches an object after it is destructed, then you get undefined behavior.  If the detached thread manages to avoid that, then it simply disappears when the process hands control back to the host system.
Bullet 3:


if I join, there is the expected behavior, but a signal kills all threads


The join() will cause main() to wait forever since the threads are in an infinite loop.  No threads ever exit and so no join() ever returns.
Control-C sends a SIGINT to any of the threads (including possibly main()).  The default behavior is for the thread that receives the signal to terminate the entire process.  As under the first two bullets, if still-running threads manage to avoid undefined behavior by not touching destructed objects, they simply disappear when control is handed back to the OS.
Fun fact:  cout is never destructed but of course will disappear when control is handed back to the OS.

Thank you for the detailed response. Follow up: are you suggesting that despite calling exit, threads may still be scheduled at the same time that static program objects and those present in main() are destructed? Does this mean that thread.detach() should be avoided?

Yes, threads not joined by the time main returns will continue to run during the atexit chain execution.  For this reason many people avoid thread.detach() like the plague. I admit that I do use thread.detach() with care. You don't want threads accessing destructed objects, whether during process shutdown or any other time.  Sometimes I use thread.detach() when I want to build a more complex "joining system" than thread.join() allows.  Perhaps signaling with a condition_variable for example.  You may also be interested in the C++20 jthread which joins in its destructor.
